# How do I get Emacs bindings in Textmate?

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts, textmate, key-bindings

In [Textmate: Power Editing for the Mac](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/097873923X), the author says that Textmate has Emacs key bindings.  When I try to use them in Textmate some work and some don't work.  For example C-n moves the cursor down one line, but C-p runs some command that gives me weird output (it doesn't move up one line).  Is there a way in Textmate to lookup what a key binding does (like Emacs' help command)?  Why are some Emacs key bindings being overridden by other commands and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some Emacs key bindings available. <kbd>^</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>^</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>^</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>^</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>, etc., work as they do in Emacs (in fact, most of those will work in *any* Cocoa app). You can see a more complete list [here](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/Site/System%20Bindings.html) (scroll down about ⅔ of the way down the page). However, active bundles may interfere with some of the these bindings, in which case you can edit the bundle by going to Bundles > Bundle Editor. Also, not *all* Emacs bindings work.

Comment: Is there an easy way you can figure out what command C-p is bound to?

Comment: Bundles > Select Bundle Item will show you the current bundle items and keybindings in use. Or you can just hit C-p and see what happens...

Comment: Right, but if it does something unexpected or returns weird output, I have no idea which command it was or which bundle it came from.  Emacs' help command will tell you which function will run for a given key binding.

Comment: Well, Bundles > Select Bundle will show all the current bundle items and their key bindings.

Comment: I want to search by key binding but I must search by bundle item order.  It feels like I am referencing a phone book, but in reverse.  It looks like this is the best that TextMate can do. =)

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://github.com/defunkt/textmate.el a textmate-mode for emacs.

Comment: This is the reverse.  This is for getting TextMate bindings in Emacs.  I'm looking to use Emacs bindings in TextMate :).